# Error Code: 1126. Can't open shared library 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\plugin\semisync_master.so'

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am using MySQL 5.6 running on 64-bit Microsoft Windows Server 2012R2, as I run the following query

**INSTALL PLUGIN rpl_semi_sync_master SONAME 'semisync_master.so**';

there is an error will generates, "*Error Code: 1126. Can't open shared library 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\plugin\semisync_master.so*' (errno: 126 The specified module could not be found". Please help me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile your library as a .dll using Visual Studio. .so's are not compatible with Windows.